# How to check if db connection is open? (mysql2 node.js)

Tags: node.js, mysql2

Dear stackoverflowers:)
I am making my first mvc application on node.js and have such a problem:
Sometimes, when I don't make any queries to the database for a long time (about 3 mins) and try to do one, I have such an error: "This Socket Has Been Ended By The Other Party"
I found out, that this is because of wait_timeout option in mysql config which closes the connection if downtime is more than value
So am i right that i should check connection for being open before every query to database? And if i should, how and where?
This my db connection file:

```
const mysql = require('mysql2');

// create the connection to database
const connection = mysql.createConnection({
    host: 'localhost',
    user: 'mysql',
    password: 'mysql',
    database: 'qa'
});

exports.connect = (done) => {
    connection.connect((err) =>{
        if(err){
            console.log('db connection error');
        }
        else{
            done()
        }
   })
}

exports.connection = connection;
```

And this is the part of one of my models:

```
const db = require('../db');
exports.makeNewQuestion = async (topic, text, subsection, user) => {
    return db.connection.promise().execute("INSERT INTO `questions` (`topic`, `text`, 
    `subsection_id`, `user_id`) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)", [topic, text, subsection, user]);
}
```

Comment: You should get the timeout value to a reasonable value (not 3 minutes) for the starting point.

Comment: `mysql2.createConnection()` will raise an error if server killed the connection.

Consider using `mysql2.createPool(...)` instead, it would reconnect with little cost depending on your configurations. By default pool may holds up to 10 connections. See https://www.npmjs.com/package/mysql2#using-connection-pools too see details about configuration options.

Answer (score 3):

As far as I know you don't need a query an existent table to check the connection/
You can use something like:

```sql
select 1
```

If that works you are connected.

Normally you don't need this approach, apart if you need to leave the connection open in the long term. 
Depending on the library you are using you can receive a Promise back. Every time you query your db you might want to check if that promise was refused or not and handle the problem accordingly.